# Java design pattern query - keeping different contexts within a single class

Tags: java, design-patterns

Wanted to get your opinion about what the best way to proceed with writing a class. So, in simplest terms, let me describe what I am trying to do.

I have a server logic layer (Logic layer) that talks to a server messaging layer (Msg layer) that talks to the client. The Logic layer issues a series of "related" commands/requests to the client, before issuing a different set of "related" commands.

So, for example, Logic layer may issue commands C1, C2, and C3 to the client by calling Func1 of Msg layer. Func1 of Msg layer will send C1 to client, wait for a response, send C2 to client, wait for a response, send C3 to the client, and wait for a response. Using the responses to C1, C2, and C3, and other arguments (A1) that were initially passed from the Logic layer to the Msg layer, Func1 will pass the final result back to the Logic layer by calling some function. So essentially, the Msg layer doesn't "bother" the Logic layer until all the client feedback is received - so it also needs to maintain context between the different commands.

At this point (after the C1, C2, C3 set is complete), the Logic layer may issue brand new commands C4, C5, C6, and C7 by calling Func2 of the Msg layer - and Func2 may also receive some other common arguments (A2) further to the commands.

How would you structure this? Particularly, how would you 'store' the common arguments - e.g. A1 while C1, C2, C3 all complete? In C++ you could use a union of multiple structures - and depending on whether Func1 or Func2 that is processing the current set of commands, you would use the appropriate structure from within the union.

In Java, how would you do it? I don't think it's "clean" to have unneeded variables just declared and sitting idly. With this approach, if I have 10 Func handler functions, then I may need 10 different structures. Don't like.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're saying some of the parameters are common to multiple commands and some are specific, I think the best approach is creating a class hierarchy.
What is common between commands keep in the base class, the rest in the child classes.
Your function in the messaging layer can accept the base class as parameter, so any child class instance would be a valid substitute.
Also at this point if you must handle many object types, factory classes or builder methods may help.

Think of this class hierarchy like a messenger between the logic layer and the messaging layer. Neither of these layers should know or care about each others particularities. The less they know of each other the better.

If all this is inside a server (as you mentioned in the beginning) then I would assume multi-threading is going to come into the picture at some time. Mostly because of this I generally caution people with storing common parameters between multiple instances. Unless you are really tight with memory just let each instance have its own copy, it's just safer and simpler.

On the other hand, if your common parameters are more in the lines of settings or configurations, then sure, go ahead and make them generally available, but also make sure you have some mechanism of detecting change (i.e. throw exceptions if someone tries to modify something it shouldn't).